# Error: Backbone is not defined

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to run a very simple an basic sample of a backbone model that is found on a tutorial for learning the library.

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.string/2.3.3/underscore.string.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.1.2/backbone-min.js"></script>

<script>

User = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        alert("Backbone model initialized");
    }
});

var user = new User;

</script>
```

But on the console there are 2 errors :

**Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'each'** on the backbone-min file

**Uncaught ReferenceError: Backbone is not defined**

And is not working.
Would yo please help me understand what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like `backbone.js` is failing to execute properly in your browser (and so it doesn't end up defined and things using it can't use it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not loading the full underscore library. Replace the second script tag with the following:

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.6.0/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the reason.